# Perl - search and replace across multiple lines across multiple files in specified directory

Tags: perl

At the moment this code replaces all occurences of my matching string with my replacement string, but only for the file I specify on the command line.  Is there a way to change this so that all .txt files for example, in the same directory (the directory I specify) are processed without having to run this 100s of times on individual files?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(INFILE,  "<",  $filename) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]";
my(@fcont) = <INFILE>;
close INFILE;

open(FOUT,">$filename") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fcont) {
 $line =~ s/\<br\/\>\n([[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][A-Z])/\n$1/gm;
print FOUT $line;
 }
 close INFILE;
```

I have also tried this:

```
perl -p0007i -e 's/\<br\/\>\n([[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][A-Z])/\n$1/m' *.txt
```

But have noticed that is only changes the first occurence of the matched pattern and ignores all the rest in the file.

I also have tried this, but it doesn't work in the sense that it just creates a blank file:

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $source_dir = "C:/Testing2";

# Store the handle in a variable.
opendir my $dirh, $source_dir or die "Unable to open directory: $!";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $dirh;
closedir $dirh;

# Stop script if there aren't any files in the list
die "No files found in $source_dir" unless @files;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  say "Processing $source_dir/$file";
  open my $in, '<', "$source_dir/$file" or die "Unable to open $source_dir/$file: $!\n";
  open(FOUT,">$source_dir/$file") || die("Cannot Open File");

    foreach my $line (@files) {
        $line =~ s/\<br\/\>\n([[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][A-Z])/\n$1/gm;
        print FOUT $line;
    }
    close $in;
}
say "Status: Processing of complete";
```

Just wondering what am I missing from my code above?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
opendir(DIR,"your_directory");
my @all_files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

for (@all_files) .....
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I incorporate my search and replace code within the for (@all_files) loop?

Comment: user1418706 are you able to elaborate more in how I should structure my code?